# AngularJS routing url remove this "#!"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My url is localhost/kaiweb/**#!**/    I want to remove that "#!" or whatever might cause this. Another example localhost/kaiweb/#!/minust  - it stays in between and don't look pretty.

```
  <li><a id="mainBtn" href="#!/" ng-class="{activeSmall:part == 'index'}" >Avaleht</a></li>
  <li><a id="aboutBtn" href="#!/minust" ng-class="{activeSmall:part == 'minust'}">Minust</a></li>
  <li><a id="workBtn" href="#!/portfoolio" ng-class="{activeSmall:part == 'portfoolio'}" >Portfoolio</a></li>
  <li><a id="vouchBtn" href="#!/teenused" ng-class="{activeSmall:part == 'teenused'}" >Teenused</a></li>
```

AngularApp

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('kaidoweb', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'pages/index.html',
         activetab: 'index',
         controller: HomeCtrl 
       }).
        when('/portfoolio', {
          templateUrl: 'pages/works.html',
          controller: PrivacyCtrl,
          activetab: 'portfoolio'
        }).
        when('/minust', {
          templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
          controller: AboutCtrl,
          activetab: 'minust'
        }).
          when('/teenused', {
          templateUrl: 'pages/teenused.html',
          controller: TeenusedCtrl,
          activetab: 'teenused'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]).run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$browser', '$timeout', "$route", function ($scope, $http, $browser, $timeout, $route) {

        $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (scope, next, current) {
          $scope.part = $route.current.activetab;
        });
```

I'm guessing it's a simple thing to fix but I'm quite new to angular.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. Try reading the docs regarding `html5mode`: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#-location-service-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that Angular is not a server side process. You can tweak the html5mode but that is only functional for links included in html anchors of your page and how the url looks like in the browser address bar. Attempting to request a subpage without the hashtag (with or without html5mode) from anywhere outside the page will result in a 404 error. For example, the following CURL request will result in a page not found error, irrespective of html5mode:

```
$ curl http://foo.bar/portfolio
```

although the following will return the root/home page:

```
$ curl http://foo.bar/#/portfolio
```

So in cases that you want to share a url with others, you have no option but to include the hashtag; unless you resolve to some type of server side routing.